# Не работает хук для описания товара woocommerce_single_product_summary для Woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Хочу получить текст для карточки товара, а конкретно написать регулярку для замены определенного контента,но не могу получить сам контент пишу следующеее в functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 'woo_excerpt', 20);
function woo_excerpt($content){
     echo"<!--.$content."-—>";//пусто
     return $content;
}
```

Comment: Нет такого хука woocommerce_template_single_excerpt. Есть woocommerce_single_product_summary. Исправил заголовок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция add_filter записана неправильно. В ней первый параметр - название хука, второй - имя пользовательской функции, третий - приоритет, четвертый - число передаваемых параметров в пользовательскую функцию.

И вообще, это не фильтр, а action. Надо так:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woo_excerpt', 10, 2 );
function woo_excerpt( $array, $int ) { 
    var_dump($array);
    var_dump($int);
};
```

Но вызов action не даёт возможности изменить текст краткого описания товара. Для этого есть фильтр woocommerce_short_description:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'filter_woocommerce_short_description', 10, 1 ); 
function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $post_post_excerpt ) { 
    // Применяйте свою регулярку к $post_post_excerpt здесь
    return $post_post_excerpt; 
};
```

И хотя в вопросе написано excerpt (краткое описание товара), и код выше именно для него, но я полагаю, что есть желание исправить полное описание товара. А оно выводится во вкладках. Фильтр для вкладок:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'filter_woocommerce_product_tabs', 10, 1 ); 
function filter_woocommerce_product_tabs( $woocommerce_default_product_tabs ) { 
    // учтите, что $woocommerce_default_product_tabs это массив
    return $woocommerce_default_product_tabs; 
};
```

Из комментариев автора - вот что выводит var_dump($woocommerce_default_product_tabs):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, что в массиве только указатели на обработчики табов.

Смотрим текст функции woocommerce_product_description_tab в файле wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_product_description_tab' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_product_description_tab() {
        wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
    }
}
```

Видно, что эту функцию можно перекрыть своей, но лучше всё-таки использовать шаблон `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php`. Его надо скопировать в папку своей дочерней темы `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php` и поправить.

Но можно поступить ещё проще, если нужно изменить только описание товара. Видим, что для вывода самого описания в description.php используется the_content(); Это стандартная функция WordPress, к которой можно применить фильтр в functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_content' );
function filter_content( $content ) {
  // Фильтр...
  return $content;
}
```

Проблема тут ровно одна - через этот фильтр полетят как описания всех товаров, так и контент страниц, записей и т.д. Если фильтр таков, что сработает только на товарах - ок. Но если отличить контент товара от записи сложно, то лучше поправить последнюю строку в description.php:

```
<?php // the_content(); ?>
<?php $content = get_the_content();
// фильтр...
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: а есть ещё одна схожая проблема, как получить контент из табов
используя вашу функцию add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'filter_woocommerce_product_tabs', 10, 1 );  возвращается такой массив
`(
    [description] => Array
        (
            [title] => Описание
            [priority] => 10
            [callback] => woocommerce_product_description_tab
        )

    [additional_information] => Array
        (
            [title] => Дополнительная информация
            [priority] => 20
            [callback] => woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab
        )

)`

Comment: Так последний сниппет в ответе как раз и получает все табы. Посмотрите на этот массив, там есть таб с ключом description, кажется.

Comment: смотрите, печатаю таб возвращается массив
https://prnt.sc/fab54f  в колбеке вижу  woocommerce_product_description_tab   пишу следующее 
`function woo_new_product_tab_content($text) {
 var_dump($text);///пусто 
}`
Что дописать чтобы появился текст таба?

Comment: дополнил ответ.